# Recent OneDrive Update is not installing on my Windows Phone 8.1. Mobile is up to date

Tags: update, onedrive

OneDrive is not updating.It's saying attention required each and every time. When I tapped on it its saying check your phone software is up to date. My mobile is up to date. But even its not installing.

Comment: What is your base OS? What steps did you perform? Did you try uninstalling it and trying to install it?